# Intermittent access to a folder on a network share

Tags: windows, networking, nas

I and my colleagues are having some network issues. We have access to a NAS device, using Windows authentication, and each of us has that device mapped to a drive letter. Within this drive are multiple folders, which we all have read/write permissions for. However, recently our access to one of those folders has become sketchy. We are sporadically unable to open and view the contents of the folder, while our IT administrator insists that no settings have been changed. Logging out and logging back in doesn't help, nor does rebooting, nor remapping the drive. Other folders on the same drive letter can be opened fine.

We have a VPN with which we can log in to the office network from home. Oddly, if we turn on the VPN while in the office, we can (sometimes) access the misbehaving folder. However, this is not reliable.

Another workaround, suggested by the IT administrator, was to add a second mapping to the NAS using a different drive letter but connecting using the device's IP rather than its hostname. This also solves the problem in some cases, but again not reliably, and has the additional downside that some links between files no longer work.

The connection issues are not consistent - sometimes I can connect to the folder while my colleague can not, or vice versa. It is also sometimes possible to open *subfolders* without error, while receiving an error for the folder itself.

We (and IT) are currently out of ideas. Can anyone help?

---

We generally receive one of two messages. The English equivalent of these error messages:

```
Restoring Network Connections. An error occurred while reconnecting S: to \\ourNAS\foldername.
Microsoft Windows Network: The local device name is already in use. The connection has not been restored.
```

```
Access Denied. The location is not accessible.
```

Comment: How did you create the mappings? Are there any firewalls or other security software? What is the NAS?

Comment: Mappings: via Windows Explorer, right click on computer -> map network drive, with reconnect ticked and other credentials unticked. The NAS is a Synology device. We're cabled on a NAT network, I know we have an external firewall but don't know if it's active within the NAT as well, I'll have to ask IT about that and security software.

Comment: Ask also about the possibility of network glitches.

Comment: There could be many causes, but I'd start with... 1) If a name is being used, what IP addresses does it resolve to? (Is there more than one? Could it be that IPv4 is flaky while IPv6 works fine, or vice versa?) 2) Is there Active Directory involved? With AD, both the client and the NAS need to be able to talk to the domain controller to verify your account. 3) In general, if the problem is somewhat easily reproducible, having Wireshark open (capturing port 445) might give _some_ hints as to where the problem is.

Comment: Open Command.   NET USE T: \\device\folder and authenticate.  Do you get a numerical error?   NET USE folder mapping is more reliable than browsing.

Comment: @John My colleague is currently suffering the glitch; he entered NET USE T: \\device\folder and hit enter, wasn't asked to authenticate. The mapping was created successfully. When clicking on the newly created drive letter, the system thought for a few seconds and then told him he didn't have access; first the second error message above, directly followed by the first.

Comment: Aha, a data point: after trying a second time, with a third drive letter U. Command 'U:' was succesful. Command 'dir' shows a volume, volume serial number, and then attempts to list the directory; but after printing `<dir>    . ` and thinking for a second, it returns the error 'File not found.' (but without an error code).
From here, he can still successfully CD into any of the subfolders.